# Encapsulating C# GUI components in a DLL

Tags: c#, user-interface, dll

I am charged with designing a system composed of 1) a GUI that handles communication with a device and 2) DLLs that represent modes in which the device will operate.

Each mode requires different configuration details so the idea is to have each DLL contain a method to produce a control-filled panel that can be placed in the GUI.

My work in C# up to now has been a bit less involved and I'm not sure how to implement this kind of functionality.  I have not been successful in locating help or examples of this kind of implementation.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a base dll that has your interfaces and base classes. The other dll's will then reference that base dll and extend/derive/implement those base classes/interfaces.

For example, if you have a dll (Base.dll) that has an interface like:

```
public interface CoolGui {
  void DrawGui(Graphics g); 
}
```

Then your other two dll's (One.dll and Two.dll) will reference Base.dll and implement CoolGui in their UI.

EDIT:

And of course, you will need to load in your dll's dynamically and use reflection to get the correct instances of your interface/base class. Here's a codeproject article to help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DynLoadClassInvokeMethod.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the reponses!  My goal was to write the GUI as an EXE that has a class to handle to device communication and have one DLL per operation mode.  Each DLL would have a method that returned a GUI panel populated with GUI controls.  It's this method that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: That's fine, you'll need a base dll that defines all the common interface/ui stuff. Make sure these are public classes and then your other dll's just need to inherit from this. As for the exe, it will load all dll's in a given directory, then use reflection to load the appropriate classes from those dll's.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to be able to dynamically load DLLs? Check out [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile.aspx). From there you can use its members and GetMember to load static members from classes in the DLL, all dynamically. I suggest calling a method that will return a shared interface (referenced by both programs) or something because without doing that it can be difficult to get around.